# Git is ignoring my changed file

Tags: git

I've got the following output on a git status:

> Changes to be committed:
>    (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
>
> ```
>    modified:   Views/Deploy/Index.cshtml
> ```
>
> Changes not staged for commit:
>    (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
>    (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
>
> ```
>    modified:   DeployController.cs
> ```

However, running

```
git add deploycontroller.cs
```

doesn't seem to do anything. It will pause the console window for just a moment as if it's working, but there's no output or anything, and another git status will show it's still unstaged.

I've used the following commands:

```
git check-ignore * **/* | grep deploycontroller.cs
git ls-files -v | grep deploycontroller.cs
```

which showed that it's not in an ignored, skip-worktree, or assume-unchanged status (when running those commands, there was no feedback from the console, but when run from a higher level to a generic folder, it correctly displayed ignored files, for instance)

And finally, I tried

```
git add --force deploycontroller.cs
```

No dice - it pauses as though it's working, but it doesn't add it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try `git add DeployController.cs`? Case sensitive...

Comment: It says it's `DeployController.cs` that's been modified, but you're adding `deploycontroller.cs`. Try using the actual name of the file.

Comment: Don't you use tab completion in your terminal?

Comment: I was not aware that it's a case-sensitive thing. It gives an error if the file isn't found, but not if you use the wrong capitalization?? very strange. either way, @JRLambert if you add your comment as a response, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone unsure, my solution was as simple as a case sensitivity issue. When I tried

```
git add deploycontroller.cs
```

It would work for a moment as if it had done something, but there were no changes to anything as far as I could tell. That being said, I didn't get any error messages.

When I tried

```
git add fdajklfjdsaklfsa.cs
```

It would give me a fatal error stating that it couldn't find the specified file, which led me to believe the first command was functional. Thanks to JRLambert, I was able to determine that git simply wasn't giving an error message for the first command, despite it not working.

When I tried

```
git add DeployController.cs
```

everything worked as expected.